# Firebase functions deploy npm error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer 0f ajv@A6.0.0 but none is installed.
You must install peer dependencies yourself.

[image: Command prompt]

Answer (score 0):

Install [ajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv) package before running application. `ajv-keywords` need it first